# How do you level-out unlevel plywood subflooring?

Tags: flooring, floor, subfloor, laminate-floor, self-leveling-concrete

On concrete floors you can pour self-leveling cement to fill valleys. How do you fill valleys on plywood sub-flooring?

Comment: You go in the basement and fix the sagging joists if you have access to them.

Comment: It depends on how large an area needs leveled. There are leveling compounds for plywood and OSB floors, but they are pricy and not practical for a large area.

Comment: You don't. You rip that crap out and put the proper thickness plywood that won't dip. Or add more but then your transitions are too high. On concrete floors you *can* pour self-leveling, but you'd better know how to trowel; that shit ain't magic. You're looking for it to be *true* more than *level*.